# How to make the rest of the code wait until zipfile finishes compiling files

Tags: python, asynchronous, google-drive-api, python-zipfile

I'm writing a script that compresses multiple files and then uploads the zip file into Google Drive. I managed to do both of these actions separately but when I do them together the uploading begins before the files have been zipped.

```
# final part of the creating zip file process:
with zipfile.ZipFile(zipFileName+".zip", "w") as zf:
    for f in myFiles:
        zf.write(f)
        print(f)

# last part of the uploading process
file_name = (zipFileName+'.zip')
metadata = {'name': file_name,
            'mimeType': None
            }

res = DRIVE.files().create(body=metadata, media_body=file_name).execute()
if res:
    print('Uploaded "%s" (%s)' % (file_name, res['mimeType']))
```

My hypothetical solution is to make the zipfile process wait but I'm not sure how to go about that.

Comment: I doubt it. Unless you explicitly use threading or multiprocessing, python is synchronous.

Comment: "make the zipfile process wait"? According to your code you have one thread sequentially zipping then uploading. Zipping is complete when the `with` clause exits, then you do the upload. There is nothing to wait for.

Comment: The beginning of the google drive auth process (under the with statement):
    try:
        import argparse
        flags = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[tools.argparser]).parse_args()
    except ImportError:
        flags = None

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially what worked for me:

```
zipFileName = input("What do you want to call the zip file?: ")
try:
    zipTheFiles(zipFileName)
except:
    print("Failed to zip the files")
else:
    shipIt(zipFileName)
```

I split the code into two functrions and placed them in a try,except,else statement