Can't upload file to a supabase bucket correctly with python
I am trying to upload a zipfile to a supabase bucket and update the root version, so the various devices can check for the latest "root" version and download the zip file if the version is more recent. The versioning update works correctly and the file is uploaded but the size doesn't match. It is always 416 bytes in the bucket, but the original file is 40kb+.
Here is the python code extract :
# Zip and upload bondz app client
import paramiko
import os
import zipfile
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import sys
import requests
from supabase import create_client, Client

load_dotenv()


local_dir = "/Users/user/Documents/files"
SUPABASE_URL = os.getenv("SUPABASE_URL")
SUPABASE_KEY = os.getenv("SUPABASE_KEY")
SUPABASE_BUCKET_URL = "https://url.supabase.co/storage/v1/s3"
BUCKET_NAME = "app-packages"

sb_url = os.environ.get("SUPABASE_URL")
sb_key = os.environ.get("SUPABASE_KEY")
supabase: Client = create_client(sb_url, sb_key)

def get_root_version():

    try:
        response = (
            supabase.table("devices").select("*").eq("device_name", "root").execute()
        )
       
        return {
            "major_version": response.data[0]["major_version"],
            "minor_version": response.data[0]["minor_version"],
            "patch_version": response.data[0]["patch_version"],
        }
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))


def get_new_version(update_type):
    app_version = get_root_version()
    print(app_version)
    if update_type == "major_version":
        app_version["major_version"] += 1
    elif update_type == "minor_version":
        app_version["minor_version"] += 1
    elif update_type == "patch_version":
        app_version["patch_version"] += 1
    return app_version

def zip_dir(version):
    """Zip a directory"""
    print(version)
    zip_filename = f"bondz_client-v{version["major_version"]}_{version["minor_version"]}_{version["patch_version"]}.zip"
    print(f"Zipping {zip_filename}")
    try:
        with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_filename, "w", zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as zipf:
            for root, _, files in os.walk(local_dir):
                for file in files:
                    file_path = os.path.join(root, file)
                    arcname = os.path.relpath(file_path, local_dir)
                    zipf.write(file_path, arcname)
        print("File zipped successfully.")
        return file_path,zip_filename
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error zipping files: {e}")


def upload_zip(file_path,filename):
    try:
        with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
            supabase.storage.from_(BUCKET_NAME).upload(file=f,path=filename, file_options={"content-type": "application/zip", "upsert": "true"})
            print(f"File {filename} uploaded successfully.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error uploading: {e}")

def update_root_version(new_version):
    try:
        data, count = supabase.table('devices').update({update_type : new_version[update_type]}).eq('device_name', 'root').execute()
        print("Db updated successfully.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error updating db: {e},{data},{count}")

update_type = sys.argv[1]
match = any(update_type == word for word in ["major_version","minor_version","patch_version"])
if match:
    new_version = get_new_version(update_type)
    file_path, filename = zip_dir(new_version)
    upload_zip(file_path,filename)
    update_root_version(new_version)
else:
    print(f"{update_type} is not a valid argument.")


Any idea ?

maybe first check what you have in uploaded file in bucket. Maybe there is some warning message instead of file.

Thx. I did and there is a file but it's only 416 bytes. I edited the question to clarify.

did you open this file? Maybe it has some information.

did you check if you send correct file? Maybe you sends different file (or from different folder) and this file has only 416 bytes. Did you use /full/path/to/file?

do you see message "File {filename} uploaded successfully." when you run it? Maybe it raise error. and if it raise error then did you try to run without try/except to see FULL error message? Did you try with smaller files? Maybe it has some limit for data. Did you tried with different bucket? Maybe problem makes bucket (or its name).

@furas I do not have any error message, I am sure the correct file is uploaded (as it is created in that same script). I can try another bucket but it works fine if I manually upload the correct file. I edited the question so you have more context. Thx.

Actually I tried to list the file size right after the zipping and I get to this issue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60309428/how-to-make-the-rest-of-the-code-wait-until-zipfile-finishes-compiling-files
